# How to create dynamic URL in Laravel right after the root domain name?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route for pages,

```
Route::get('{id}', 'User\HomeController@single');
```

And I expect the URL like

```
example.org/this-is-my-page
```

but I am getting 404 error. Also I have Routes like,

```
Route::get('/admin', 'Sitezontroller@home')->name('admin');
Route::get('/products', 'SiteController@products')->name('products');
```

And I don't want to get conflicted this URL with my page URL. Could anybody here help me, please?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do some URLs start with a `/` and the one for the ID does not?

Comment: That route should be last, so it can "catch" all routes that don't match the one above.

Comment: both will work. I just put it like that

Comment: @Mozammil I tried that but still I getting 404.

Comment: Can you show what's in your `HomeController@single`?

Comment: @Mozammil . Thanks, it works fine now :)

Comment: @piscator As Mozammil Mentioned, I put the Route in end of the file now its woks fine

Comment: your route is correct, i think you have problem in your controller and it`s namespace

Comment: @atf.sgf yeah it's working now. Earlier I put the route on top of other routes that why I received the 404 error